# Overcoming small dataset anomalies in genetic algorithm

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, polynomial, genetic-algorithms

So I am currently making my 6th version of a model designed to predict the likelihood of of a particular medical condition based on a multifactorial genetic markers and I really would appreciate some advice with regards to a method to overcome this problem. The model I have used thus far has proved very successful, but I know there is still one thing I am not accounting for statistically.

The data I have for this medical condition is particularly limited. For some parameters I have multiple candidate genetic markers lets call this one GM1, the likelihood of developing this particular medical condition is now being shown to be related to the number of repeats of this genetic marker. However when modeling them, I run into issues with limited data for some number of repeats.

Parameter 1
For instance for 12 repeats of this genetic marker I could have 1000 people with 100 of them developing the condition. I input this into my model by checking what the % of people displaying 12 repeats was against the actual number that showed in a new test dataset so in this case 10% into my polynomial regression yields 8.7% chance of developing the condition. However in the same polynomial regression 35 repeats of the the genetic marker is also input as a 10% being 1 confirmed case from 10 people showing the same 8.7% chance of developing the condition.

The way in which my model works is it assigns different weights to over 600 different parameters in order to best predict the actual multifactorial causation within the genetic profile. For instance parameter 2 would be a different genetic marker and a polynomial regression would be performed on the % of model data patients against the number of real observed and the same as for parameter 1, a 10% chance could input into the polynomial regression as a result of multiple different numbers of repeats of this genetic marker.

What I need to know is how to adjust for different size datasets. Depending on what size dataset made up the original % chance of developing the condition. 
I am open to suggestion with regards to a method to achieve this.

Comment: What does the sentence " I input this into my model by checking what the % of people displaying 12 repeats was against the actual number that showed in a new test dataset so in this case 10% into my polynomial regression yields 8.7% chance of developing the condition." mean?  This sentence contains 44 words and not a single punctuation mark.

Comment: Good question, Ok so essentially I have been provided with two sets of data. One for producing my model and one for testing the model. Seems a strange way of doing It I know, but there are several groups of scientists working on the same model, and this has been the method for comparing the future predictive qualities of the models we create. (essentially I think they are just making sure we don't overfit.)

Comment: So in answering your question using a polynomial regression of "the percentage of patients displaying 12 genetic marker repeats"  against the "future incidence of patients who have this genetic marker repeat who also have the condition (again expressed as a %)."

Comment: Because of the low numbers of data making up the initial % the resultant and observed strike rate % is significantly lower.

Comment: Essentially I am asking how do I make adjustments for (new example) 1/3 (33.3%) and 10/30 (33.3%) the latter needs to be given more statistical significance within the model. I can see this by looking at the resultant (post data) strike rates of each of these  inputs. 1/3 yields a resultant strike rate of just 18% meaning all inputs that are 1/3 contain anomalies which brings down the resultant strikerate. However when it is 10/30 the resultant strike rate is 30%. My polynomial regression however however shows that if you input 33.3% you are given 20.2% as a resultant strike rate....

Comment: So it is clear that all the small sample size pieces of data are influencing the polynomial regression. What I need to be able to do is take into account the dataset size  for each of the input parameters. But I am unsure of the best method to do this. I can probably think up a novel way of achieving this, but I thought there may well be some previously well tested and well accepted method. I cannot however just discount the low sample size pieces of data because they do bear an influence and obviously do occur in the post model data too. Thoughts? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can make out, you have 1000+ patients, one disease which the patients either have or do not have, and about 600 genetic markers, for which you have number of copies of that marker.

What you have done with that is to run a polynomial regression of the number of repeats against the disease prevalence. You then have some kind of model (you don't specify what kind) which weights the predicted proportions from the 600 or so univariate polynomial regressions to make a unified prediction of the prevalence, which you test on a hold-out data set. You are running into problems because you may have very few patients with a particular number of repeats, meaning the prevalence could be quite biased.

I'll be basing my answer on this interpretation of your question.

OK, the answer: To begin with, I think you may not be formulating your problem in the best way.

Right now you have:

1. A matrix of counts of repeats of 600 markers for each of ~1,000 patients
2. A boolean vector of whether or not each patient has the condition you want to predict

The more conventional way to handle this problem would be to train a classifier on this data directly. If you particularly like regression, you could go with logistic regression, but you could also use a more sophisticated classifier like a support vector machine or random forest. All of these methods can output either absolute predictions, or probabilities, for each individual patient you feed into them.

To validate this on your test set, you make a prediction for each patient, and create a truth table against the true disease state. This will let you compute the accuracy (or most likely you want something like both sensitivity and specificity). If you want to be more sophisticated, you could take the probabilities, and compute the area under the receiver operating curve (AUROC), which gives a global measure of the tradeoff between sensitivity and specificity.

This approach is much more in line with what you will see in the literature, and avoids most of the problems (and the complexity) you have introduced into your problem, and quite likely will give you much better predictions.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer, I have been used to using Stack Overflow but this was my first question on cross validated and I was beginning to think that this was an inactive forum. :)

Comment: Your answer is very well written and I will assume you come from more of a modeling background than myself! As such you have expressed I am in competition with some modeling teams, and currently my model is winning hands down. I think they have overlooked the use of genetic algorithm to weight the different parameters.

Comment: Your suggestion of training a classifier on this data directly is both interesting and out of my comfort zone. But I will look into it. How do these other suggested methods work to take into account smaller sample sizes?

Comment: Your particular issue of per-reading sample size is completely obviated by these methods, as they take the entire patient sample at once. They can be susceptible to major imbalances in your outcome variable (e.g. if only 10% of your overall training set patients have the disease, then the classifier will tend to overfit to the 90% who are healthy). It doesn't seem like this is  an issue in your dataset, but if it is, you can use methods like balanced bagging to resolve it.

Comment: What is the actual metric being used to decide which models are better in this competition?

Comment: I should add that running these classifiers (e.g. SVM or random forests) is only a few lines of code in R (or the programming language of your choice). If you're using R, you might want to look at the caret package, which provides a whole framework for classification, with a lot of detail about how to go about it in the vignette.

Comment: Accuracy and accuracy only.

Comment: I currently use python only. (Have spent last 4 months trying to learn it)

Comment: Random forests, SVM, and most other best of breed classifiers are definitely available for Python, and run in just a few lines of code. Here's an example for random forests: http://pythonhosted.org/milk/randomforests.html

Comment: As I've said, I think the correct solution to your problem is to reformulate it to use a classifier.

However, if you absolutely must use your regression/genetic algorithm approach, a solution to your exact problem as stated in the question might be to use weighted regression, with the number of patients supporting each data point as your weights. Apparently this Python package will do weighted least squares: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels

Comment: Weighted regression, this may be what I am looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction and for providing me with other alternative methods. Many thanks!